# How to set interaction endpoint on discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to set a interaction endpoint and the verification isn't working.

```
@csrf_exempt
def discord_endpoint(request):
     return JsonResponse({'type':1})
```

I'm getting:

```
Validation errors:
interactions_endpoint_url: The specified interactions endpoint url could not be verified.
```

and as a post response from discord in my django app:

```
b'{"application_id":"...","entitlements":[],"id":"...","token":"...","type":1,"user":{"avatar":"...","avatar_decoration":null,"discriminator":"0","global_name":"...","id":"...","public_flags":0,"username":"nickname"},"version":1}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
@csrf_exempt
def discord_endpoint(request):

    verify_key = VerifyKey(bytes.fromhex('PUBLIC CODE'))

    signature = request.headers["X-Signature-Ed25519"]
    timestamp = request.headers["X-Signature-Timestamp"]
    body = request.body.decode("utf-8")

    try:
        verify_key.verify(f'{timestamp}{body}'.encode(), bytes.fromhex(signature))
        return JsonResponse({'type':1})
    except BadSignatureError:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'}, status=405)
```